How to refer to a generic number
I was trying to convey into Japanese the mathematics western convention for a "generic number" of something, which is N. For instance, n-people, n-parameters, n-variables, etc. I have finally found a possible translation using the specific counter for the item and the の joining particle. So, 何人の人 (なんにんの ひと) for n-people, 何冊の本, for n-books, 何本のペン, for n-pens, etc. To be honest, that's what I finally could contrive after some lengthy reasoning and searching with a a few A.I.s on the Web. The question is, do things actually work like that in real japanese language or it is just the logical outcome of an artificial-intelligence built-up, synthetic speech?

I'm not sure what you mean by "generic number", and it looks like the AI may be confused, too.
何人の人 only means "how many people?" or sometimes "whatever the number of people is":

何人の人がいますか？
How many people are there?
何人の人がいようとも壊せない。
No matter how many people there are, it's unbreakable.

If you want to use N as a placeholder and say something like "N-people" in math-related contexts, you can simply say N人:

N人の人とM冊の本とK本のペン
N people, M books and K pens
N人対戦
N-person match (video game)
Nパラメータの大規模言語モデル
large language model with N parameters
N次元空間
N-dimensional space
Nが大きい臨床研究 (colloquial jargon)
a clinical trial with a large N (i.e., a large number of participants)

Are these what you want? If you have access to AI, you would usually get better results by letting it translate a long and concrete English sentence that includes "N-person" into Japanese.

AI doesn't understand anything, so it cannot be "confused".

That' what , I did want to know.  Thank you both for answers. (Don't let's be too severe with A.I.)
